# Android Studio 3.0: Cant merge DEX

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Since I updated to Android Studio 3.0 I am no longer able to run my project on my device. I have searched Google and StackOverflow for the problem it seems Android Studio 3.0 is the problem. I have tried all the solutions on StackOverflow none of them seem to work. Also my Gradle file is quite messy because I have just added lines of code to fix problems so it would really help if someone could help me clean it up. I have researched alot before posting this.

My error is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

```
defaultConfig {
    renderscriptTargetApi 15
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    applicationId "com.firebase.android"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
}




dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.1') {
        transitive = false
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.crystal:crystalpreloaders:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.mmin18:realtimeblurview:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.6'
    compile 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:1.2.1'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.eftimoff:android-viewpager-transformers:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.zomato:androidphotofilters:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.waynell:VideoRangeSlider:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':ptr-lib')
    compile project(path: ':FFmpegAndroid')
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Update: Added Gradle log output**

Here is the Gradle Stacktrace output

```
    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
Configuration 'compile' in project ':FFmpegAndroid' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':FFmpegAndroid' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
:FFmpegAndroid:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:processDebugResources
:FFmpegAndroid:generateDebugSources
:FFmpegAndroid:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:FFmpegAndroid:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:ptr-lib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /home/gaz/AndroidStudioProjects/Dissertation/FireBaseLogin/app/google-services.json
:ptr-lib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:processDebugResources
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:ptr-lib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:generateDebugSources
:ptr-lib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:ptr-lib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:FFmpegAndroid:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ptr-lib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter;\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter;

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter;
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter;
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransform.transform(DexMergerTransform.java:230)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

53 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 46 up-to-date
```

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and post the entire output of your Gradle console, not just that one line. The details of your problem lie elsewhere in the output.

Comment: @CommonsWare I updated my question with Gradle Stacktrace please take a look. Thanks so much

Comment: `Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter`. Try simply commenting out `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'`.

Comment: Wow thanks @CommonsWare that worked. Can you explain why i was getting this error? And is there anyway to use this lib in my project without getting errors? Also do you think I could clean up my Gradle file anymore?

Comment: I really appreciate the help, If you put it as an answer I shall accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is:

```
Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/filefilter/AgeFileFilter
```

Two (or perhaps more) of your dependencies are supplying an `org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.AgeFileFilter` class. Since you happen to have `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'` in your `dependencies`, comment that out, as that library certainly provides this class.

> And is there anyway to use this lib in my project without getting errors?

Most likely, you already have the library, perhaps from a JAR. If you find that there are classes from `org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2` that you were using that you can no longer use... you now have a much bigger problem. You would need to identify what *other* dependency did something silly, such as include `org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.AgeFileFilter` in their own library. That could get complicated.

> Also do you think I could clean up my Gradle file anymore?

If you do not have any JARs in `libs/`, get rid of `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`, as you do not need that line. If you *do* have JARs in `libs/`, try to find an artifact (like most of the rest of your dependencies) and use that instead.

You appear to be using Android Studio 3.0, version `3.0.0` of the Android Gradle Plugin, and a comparable version of Gradle (e.g., 4.1). Hence, these messages will persist until you make the changes they identify:

```
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'testImplementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
Configuration 'compile' in project ':FFmpegAndroid' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'androidTestCompile' in project ':FFmpegAndroid' is deprecated. Use 'androidTestImplementation' instead.
```

Other than that, try to use fewer dependencies. Using libraries is great, as is eating a slice of cake. Using 20+ libraries is less great, as is eating 20+ slices of cake.

Comment: Why is it bad to use lots of libs? I always thought re-inventing the wheel is bad

Comment: @TheOtherguyz4kj: "Why is it bad to use lots of libs?" -- each additional library not only makes the app bigger but increases the odds of these sorts of build problems. "I always thought re-inventing the wheel is bad" -- IMHO, the objective should be to have as few wheels as possible, whether you re-invent them or use pre-fabricated wheels. To quote Einstein, "everything should be as simple as possible, but no simpler". For example, do you really need a floating search view?

Comment: When you say it like that it makes sense. Thanks